# jquery unable to add li to ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a li inside a ul using jquery. Unable to get the li added with below line. what would be the issue?

My fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3opLcLd4/)

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>

 $(".custom-menu ul:last").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
 //$(".custom-menu ul").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
 console.log($('.custom-menu').html());
```

Comment: I think it should be `li:last`

Comment: `$(".custom-menu li:last").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.after()` with `li:last`, not `.append()` or `ul:last`

```
$(".custom-menu li:last").after('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

```js
 $(".custom-menu li:last").after('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

Or you could use `.append()` with the `<ul>` by itself (no `:last` needed) with:

```
$(".custom-menu").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

as `.append()` inserts the content as the last child by default.

```js
 $(".custom-menu").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action="first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action="second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action="third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

**[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)**: Inserts content after each element in the set of matched elements.

**[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)**: Inserts content  to the end of each element in the set of matched elements. The .append() method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection

Notice the difference between the two. `.after()` inserts content after the element(s) you specify while `.append()` inserts the content as the last child of the element(s) you specify.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution is 
`$(".custom-menu").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');`, as explained by LXhelili and j08691. Since append inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection, you don't need to specify `:last`.

Edited to address comment below.

Comment: `li:last` will add the new `li` to the last `li`, so that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks, @spawnedc.  Edited my answer to reflect your input.

Answer (score 1):

This way.

```
 $(".custom-menu").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
 //$(".custom-menu ul").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
 console.log($('.custom-menu').html());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cbfys0o0/

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your selector from `.custom-menu ul:last` to `ul.custom-menu:last`.

`.custom-menu ul:last` is targeting the last `ul` element within `.custom-menu`.

`ul.custom-menu:last` is targeting the last `ul` element with the class `.custom-menu`.

[Here's an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjgz5xp3/).

Answer (score 1):

`$(".custom-menu ul:last").append` targets the last `ul` inside the `.custom-menu`, which IS the `ul` itself. What you want to do is append an `li` inside the `.custom-menu`. So your code should be:

```
 $(".custom-menu").append('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$(".custom-menu li:last").after('<li> hey test ...</li>');
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm4xzgg1/).